# Why does SSIS package fail with invalid signature after migration?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

My office just migrated from SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2017. We converted just under 100 SSIS packages to the 2017 format. We have many of these being triggered by SQL jobs. The large majority of these are running fine after the migration. However, we have a handful (maybe 10) that are sometimes failing with an invalid signature error. For those that are failing, I am not even seeing a consistent 100% failure rate.

Why are the packages failing intermittently with this error?

Below is an example of the full error text. One of the example packages was deployed to 4 different servers, and it runs fine on 3 of them. The only difference between the 4 versions is the path to the dtconfig file. We did not change anything about the jobs that call the packages.

I tried re-deploying the failing package for that example that I just mentioned, but it will still fail intermittently with an invalid signature error. In addition, I had our IT department confirm that the user under which the jobs execute has permissions to read the dtsx file.

> Executed as user: domain\username. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
>   Package Utility  Version 14.0.3045.24 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2017
>   Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  6:30:00 AM  Error:
>   2018-12-18 06:30:00.82     Code: 0xC0011007     Source:
>   {5576F0C1-D470-418D-8FAB-9700612AEF76}      Description: Unable to
>   load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML
>   format. A specific XML parser error will be posted.  End Error  Error:
>   2018-12-18 06:30:00.82     Code: 0xC0011002     Source:
>   {5576F0C1-D470-418D-8FAB-9700612AEF76}      Description: Failed to
>   open package file "\\servername\sharename\mypackage.dtsx" due to error
>   0x80090006 "Invalid Signature.".  This occurs when loading a package
>   and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML
>   document. This can be the result of specifying an incorrect file name
>   when calling LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect
>   format.  End Error  Could not load package
>   "\\servername\sharename\mypackage.dtsx" because of error 0xC0011002. 
>   Description: Failed to open package file
>   "\\servername\sharename\mypackage.dtsx" due to error 0x80090006
>   "Invalid Signature.".  This occurs when loading a package and the file
>   cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can
>   be the result of specifying an incorrect file name when calling
>   LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect format. 
>   Source: {5576F0C1-D470-418D-8FAB-9700612AEF76}  Started:  6:30:00 AM 
>   Finished: 6:30:00 AM  Elapsed:  0.016 seconds.  The package could not
>   be found.  The step failed.

Comment: You may have converted the packages to SSDT 2017, but did you build the packages as 2017 packages? the error implies, as well, that you're using the File System, deployment method. Any reason why you're not making use of SSISDB? There are a lot of benefits to using the new Project Deployment method, which also (as of SQL Server 2017) supports deploying individual packages from a project as well now.

Comment: It smells like permissions to your path. I often see the packages stored in the database rather than filesystem. If your environment allows I might try that approach. Do they run concurrently across those 4 machines targeting one network shared dtsx?

Comment: We did build the packages in SSDT 2017 and confirmed that the package xml was showing a different version. We were told to use the file system for our migration, but I don't know why. I'll have to check and see if that is an option we can consider moving forward.

Comment: The example package mentioned is deployed as 4 different files on 4 different servers.

Comment: The package is deployed in 4 parts on 4 different servers? That sounds awfully messy.

Comment: Just to clarify...this is the same single dtsx file deployed to 4 different servers. It is not split into 4 parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker found a solution that worked for us. We had to update the SQL Server jobs that called the SSIS packages. Instead of referencing UNC paths, these jobs are now referencing local paths. After making this change, we are no longer seeing the errors.

The same job definitions were working under SQL Server 2008R2. However, we did also update our server OS version at the same time, so perhaps that was a factor as well.